# Blurry profile Image from Twitter REST api

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiimage, twitterkit

is there a way I can make an image that I'm getting from twitter REST api not look blurry? I'm using this method at the moment in do catch block

```
let imgData = try Data(contentsOf: pi_url!)
let profImg = UIImage(data: imgData)
```

Comment: Make sure you're presenting it in a view who's size is <= the image.size.

Comment: @danh Care to elaborate? I have a very small rounded imageview and from the rest api, I try all the other sizes and it's still blurry but when I paste the url string into my browser, image is clear